# Proving an convexity-looking inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

> If $0 \le \alpha \le 1$ and $0 \le \lambda \le 1$, then
>   $$\lambda^\alpha x^\alpha +(1-\lambda^\alpha) y^\alpha \ge (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)^\alpha$$
>   whenever $0 \le y \le x$.

This looks like a standard sort of inequality that resembles convexity... if anyone can provide some "big picture" context, I would really appreciate it.

I've tried to prove it below, but it seems rather cumbersome. If there is a faster way, please  let me know.

---

If $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha = 1$, then the lemma holds. If $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$, then the lemma holds. If $x=0$, then $y=0$, so the lemma also holds. So, we assume $0 < \alpha < 1$, $0 < \lambda < 1$, and $x > 0$.

Note that for $0<\alpha \le 1$ and $0 < \lambda \le 1$ in the given range, we have $$1-\lambda^\alpha \ge (1-\lambda)^\alpha.$$ To see this, note that for fixed $\alpha$, the function $1-\lambda^\alpha - (1-\lambda)^\alpha$ has zeros at $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=1$ and a single critical point at $\lambda=1/2$, which is a local minimum because $\alpha < 1$. Therefore, if we show
$$\lambda^\alpha x^\alpha + (1-\lambda)^\alpha y^\alpha \ge (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)^\alpha,$$
(replacing $1-\lambda^\alpha$ with $(1-\lambda)^\alpha$), we will have proven the lemma.

Let $f(y)=\lambda^\alpha x^\alpha + (1-\lambda)^\alpha y^\alpha - (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)^\alpha$. Then,
$$f'(y) = (1-\lambda)^\alpha \alpha y^{\alpha-1} -\alpha(1-\lambda)(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)^{\alpha-1}.$$
Setting $f'(y)=0$ implies
\begin{align*}
(1-\lambda)^\alpha y^{\alpha-1} &= (1-\lambda)(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)^{\alpha-1}\\
((1-\lambda)y)^{\alpha-1} &= (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)^{\alpha-1}\\
\lambda x &= 0.
\end{align*}
Since we know $\lambda x \ne 0$ by assumption, we have a contradiction, so there is no critical point. Therefore $f$ is either increasing or decreasing for $y \ge 0$. Since $f(0)=0$ and
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\lambda^\alpha x^\alpha + (1-\lambda)^\alpha x^\alpha - x^\alpha\\
&=x^\alpha (\lambda^\alpha + (1-\lambda)^\alpha - 1)\\
&\ge x^\alpha (\lambda + (1-\lambda)-1) & \text{$0<\alpha<1$ and $0<\lambda<1$ imply $\lambda^\alpha \ge \lambda$}\\
&=0,
\end{align*}
we see that $f(y)$ is increasing for $0\le y \le x$, and therefore nonnegative.

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva It is from Ross's Probability Models textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will prove the equivalent inequality $$(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)^\alpha  - (\lambda x)^\alpha \leq (\lambda y + (1-\lambda)y)^\alpha -(\lambda y)^\alpha$$ which is obvious because $x^\alpha$ is concave and $\lambda x \geq \lambda y$, then when we add $(1-\lambda)y$ to  both $\lambda x$ and $\lambda y$ we know which increment is bigger

Comment: I apologize, I just realized that my claim that $1-\lambda^\alpha \ge (1-\lambda)^\alpha$ is wrong; the inequality should point the other way. So, the inequality that you and I proved is not as tight as the one in the lemma. How do we cope with this?

Comment: @angryavian I didn't use your claim, just proved the lemma directly.

Comment: But I think your solution involves $(1-\lambda)^\alpha$ instead of the lemma's $1-\lambda^\alpha$.

Comment: Check it carefully, the RHS is $y^\alpha - \lambda^\alpha y^\alpha$

Comment: Oops, I apologize. Thanks very much!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Note that when $0<p<1$ the function $x\mapsto x^{p}$ is subadditive on the non-negative reals so:

$$(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)^{\alpha}\le(\lambda x)^{\alpha}+((1-\lambda)y)^{\alpha}=\lambda^{\alpha}x^{\alpha}+(1-\lambda)^{\alpha}y^{\alpha}$$

To show that $x^{p}$ is subadditive first note that

$$(x+y)^{p}\le x^{p}+y^{p}$$

is clear when $y=0$ and hence if we can show it is true when $y=1$ then:

$$(x+y)^{p}=y^{p}(\frac{x}{y}+1)^{p}\le y^{p}((\frac{x}{y})^{p}+1)=x^{p}+y^{p}$$

Now just show that $f(x)=(x+1)^{p}-x^{p}$ is decreasing and $f(0)=1$.

Alternatively since

$$(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)^{\alpha}\le(\lambda x)^{\alpha}+((1-\lambda)y)^{\alpha}=\lambda^{\alpha}x^{\alpha}+(1-\lambda)^{\alpha}y^{\alpha}$$

is clear when $x=0$ we may assume $x\neq0$. We may also assume that $x=1$ since if it is true in this case then:

$(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)^{\alpha}=x^{\alpha}(\lambda+(1-\lambda)\frac{y}{x})^{\alpha}\le x^{\alpha}(\lambda^{\alpha}+(1-\lambda)^{\alpha}\frac{y^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha}})=\lambda^{\alpha}x^{\alpha}+(1-\lambda)^{\alpha}y^{\alpha}$

Now we look at the function $f(x)=(1-\lambda)^{\alpha}y^{\alpha}-(\lambda+(1-\lambda)y)^{\alpha}$ for $0\le y\le1$ (since $0\le y\le x$). $f(0)=-\lambda^{\alpha}$ and $$f'(y)=\frac{(1-\lambda)^{\alpha}}{y^{1-\alpha}}-\frac{(1-\lambda)}{(\lambda+(1-\lambda)y)^{1-\alpha}}\ge\frac{(1-\lambda)^{\alpha}}{y^{1-\alpha}}-\frac{(1-\lambda)}{(1-\lambda)^{1-\alpha}y^{\alpha}}=0$$

Comment: That's a good idea.

Comment: @NikosM. Would expansion of binomial be problematic if $p$ is not an integer?

Comment: @angryavian, there is a binomial formula for non-integer values of the exponent (my comment assumed this generalised binomial)

Comment: @angryavian, see [generalised binomial formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem)

Comment: @user71352 I apologize, I just realized that my claim that $1-\lambda^\alpha \ge (1-\lambda)^\alpha$ is wrong; the inequality should point the other way. So, the inequality that you and I proved is not as tight as the one in the lemma. How do we cope with this?